# How to view content of variable of type LPVOID

Tags: c, visual-c++, windbg

I have a C function that takes a parameter of type LPVOID. The values that gets passed in is \0 seperated array of characters. How can I cast the parameter to see the incoming value in visual studio / windbg?

Comment: A direct cast to `char*` doesn't work?

Comment: Well, yeah. Since you have NULLs separating them. You'll have to iterate through them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cast that would allow you to observe that in watch windows. For VS you will have to open up a memory window on the address at the beginning of the null separated block.

In WinDbg command `db <my_address>` dumps raw memory along with ASCII conversion. If block is larger than 128 bytes, then add option `l` to the command. E.g this will print out first 0x200 bytes for local variable pVoid:
`db poi pVoid l200`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a script. Something like the following would work, which assumes char * strings and that the list ends in double NULLs (like a MULTI_SZ):

```
$$ Print a MULTI_SZ value in the debugger. Note that 
$$ this script assume a char* string

$$ Grab the argument to the script
r @$t0 = ${$arg1}

$$ while *str != NULL
.while (by(@$t0) != 0) 
{

    $$ Print the string
    da @$t0

    $$ There's no strlen in this language, so find the NULL
    .while (by(@$t0) != 0) 
    {
        r @$t0 = @$t0 + 1
    }

    $$ String points to the NULL. Add one.
    r @$t0 = @$t0 + 1
}
```

Save to a text file and then run the following in WinDBG:

```
0:000> $$>a<c:\dumps\multisz.txt 0x012210ec
012210ec  "Foo"
012210f0  "Bar"
012210f4  "FooBar"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply casting to `char*` should work.

```
  void f(LPVOID s)
  {
      char* ss = (char*) s; // put breakpoint here or watch the variable
      for(char* r = ss; *r != '\0'; r += (strlen(r)+1)) { // iterate the string
          printf("%s \n", r);
       }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

again a very late a answer but `dpa` in windbg can be leveraged to print the list

```
lpvoid:\>dir /b
lpvoid.cpp

lpvoid:\>type lpvoid.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

    int somefunc(LPVOID blah)
    {
        printf("%s\n",*(PCHAR *)blah);
        return 0;
    }
    int main (void)
    {
        PCHAR foo[] = { "yay" , "boy" , "dog" , "cat" , "monkey" , "weedinducedweird
    o" };
        somefunc( foo);
        return 0;
    }

    lpvoid:\>cl /Zi /nologo lpvoid.cpp
    lpvoid.cpp

    lpvoid:\>dir /b *.exe
    lpvoid.exe

    lpvoid:\>lpvoid.exe
    yay
```

set a bp on somefunc or if you do not have symbols on address lik bp 401020
use dpa on the argument (blah here) or use dpa @esp+8

```
    lpvoid:\>cdb -c "bp somefunc \"dpa poi(blah) l?6;q\";g;q" lpvoid.exe | grep -A 6
     yay
    0013ff60  00417c60 "yay"
    0013ff64  00417c64 "boy"
    0013ff68  00417c68 "dog"
    0013ff6c  00417c6c "cat"
    0013ff70  00417c70 "monkey"
    0013ff74  00417c78 "weedinducedweirdo"
    quit:
```

assuming no symbols here

```
lpvoid:\>cdb -c "bp 401020 \"dpa (@esp+8) l?6;q\";g;q" lpvoid.exe | grep -A 6 ya
y
0013ff60  00417c60 "yay"
0013ff64  00417c64 "boy"
0013ff68  00417c68 "dog"
0013ff6c  00417c6c "cat"
0013ff70  00417c70 "monkey"
0013ff74  00417c78 "weedinducedweirdo"
quit:
```